How to get the ObjectId of inserted document in MongoDB reactive Java?
mongoOutputMono = Mono.from(database.runCommand(command));
JSONObject outputJson = new JSONObject(mongoOutput.toJson(documentCodec));
System.out.println("output json is " + outputJson);

Suppose I insert some document.
output json is the following
{
  "electionId": { "$oid": "7fffffff0000000000000531" },
  "$clusterTime": {
    "clusterTime": { "$timestamp": { "t": 1714592831, "i": 31 } },
    "signature": {
      "keyId": 7327356439112974337,
      "hash": {
        "$binary": { "base64": "dDUDEwRppg/l9t2C4bOqzawPQ8M=", "subType": "00" }
      }
    }
  },
  "opTime": { "t": 1329, "ts": { "$timestamp": { "t": 1714592831, "i": 31 } } },
  "ok": 1,
  "n": 1,
  "operationTime": { "$timestamp": { "t": 1714592831, "i": 31 } }
}

Apparently $oid is not the ObjectId because it's static for every insert. Is there a way to access ObjectId?
PS: I'm using import com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.MongoDatabase

Mono.from method returns a Mono (and this has the next item emitted by it). You can apply the subscribe(Consumer) method to extract / print the result. Try this and see if it works: mongoOutputMono.subscribe(doc -> System.out.println(doc));. This should print the insert result.

Further to my earlier comment; in case you still not seeing the inserted document's newly created ObjectId try one of these: (1) com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.MongoCollection.insertOne method, (2) org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.ReactiveMongoTemplate.insert method.

As per the documentation database.runCommand(insert), the output may not contain the inserted document _id value: insert command, see the Output section. So, with your present code you may not see the result as expected by you. Try my suggestion from my previous comment to print the _id value of the inserted document.
